# body of nestedscrollview overflowed - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, nestedscrollview

[image: Screenshoot App]

I made a page with `NestedScrollView`, the body of `NestedScrollView` is a container that holds data from previous requests. but the body of the `NestedScrollView` is overflowed. The following code:

```
NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollViewController,
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                title: new Text(
                  nama,
                  style: TextStyle(color: putih),
                ),
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: putih),
                backgroundColor: colorPrimaryDark,
              )
            ];
          },
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: goldtua,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          string.harga,
                          style: TextStyle(color: putih, fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          formatingRupiah(harga),
                          style: TextStyle(color: putih, fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              string.fasilitas,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                fasilitas, //this is the result of the request, the text is multiline so it takes up less space
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        ......
```

Please, can someone tell me where do I do it wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you want or need to keep using the NestedScrollView, you can use ListView instead Column to ListView, just like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage() : super();
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('My large title'),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: ListView( // This is the right way
          children: [
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You will see a screen like this.

[image]

Notice, that if you change only the ListView to column, you will get this result:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage() : super();
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text('My large title'),
            )
          ];
        },
        body: Column( // I changed here from ListView and Column and I will get an overflow error
          children: [
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
            Text("List item", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: any idea on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795503/flutter-nested-list-scroll-parent-when-reach-to-end-start-of-inner-list

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the size of your content is bigger than the size of the container. That means the `Container` size is smaller than the size of `Column`. In order to solve this issue, you should wrap `Container` with a Scrollable Widget like `SingleChildScrollView` which will scroll overflowing content and match parents size or available space. You don't need to use `Expanded` since each item of `Column` will fill only needed space

```
body:
SingleChildScrolView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: goldtua,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          string.harga,
                          style: TextStyle(color: putih, fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          formatingRupiah(harga),
                          style: TextStyle(color: putih, fontSize: 24.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              string.fasilitas,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                fasilitas, //this is the result of the request, the text is multiline so it takes up less space
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        ......
```

Comment: I've tried your code but the result i got is just a blank screen

Comment: we cant use Expanded with SingleChildScrolView

Answer (score 1):

Simply just use a `SingleChildScrollView` at the root of `body`:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[.....
```

Comment: This worked for me, but isn't a NestedScrollView's body supposed to be some kind of list/colum by itself? I mean it's supposed to be scrolled anyway, so I thought a body:(Column (mainAxisSize: min))  should not overflow. :/