# How to fix Column overflow in NestedScrollView body?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So basically I am using a `NestedScrollView` with a column body that holds a `TabBar` and `TabBarView`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              sliver: SliverAppBar(
                stretch: true,
                pinned: true,
                collapsedHeight: 400,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Biography(),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: TabBar(
                controller: this.controller,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.book)),
                  Tab(icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.music_albums)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: this.controller,
                children: [
                  // this is in reality a customscrollview
                  Container(color: Colors.red),
                  // this is in reality a customscrollview
                  Container(color: Colors.blue),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**The error:**

When I scroll up, i.e my thumb is going toward the bottom of the screen, and the `Container` that is in the `Column` reaches the bottom of the screen, it causes an overflow error. The `Expanded TabBarView` is fine, it's the `Container` that causes the overflow.

**What I've tried:**

1. I've tried to change the `Column` to a `ListView` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314623/body-of-nestedscrollview-overflowed-flutter) but it results in another error(something about hasSize). I did set `shrinkWrap: true`.
2. Use `Expanded` on the `Container` but it results in a wonky UI.
3. Wrapping the Column in a `SingleChildScrollView` but it also results in the same error as ListView.

How can I make it so the Container doesn't cause an overflow when it reaches the bottom of the screen?

Thank you!

Comment: u can use list view method by wrapping Listview inside Sized box and specify size

Comment: @DipakRamoliya The children of the TabBarView are CustomScrollViews so they don’t have a set size. I guess I shoulda specified that in the question